# How to solve extremely large systems of equations

Tags: symbolic-math, equation-solving

I need to solve a large system of equations.  The system that I need to solve now has 30 equations and 30 unknowns, but I need to be able to use this same system to solve 1,000 equations and 1,000 unknowns.  I do not need to know the answers for all of the unknown variables, I just need to know the answers for a few of them (2 in the 30 equations case, and ~10 in the 1,000 equations case).  The equations that I need to solve are each in the form:

```
(c0 * x0) + (c1 * x1) + ... + (c_n * x_n)
```

Where `x_i` is an unknown variable, `c_i` is a known constant, and `n` is the number of unknowns that I have.

Solving this system seems like it should be trivial by coding it into a matrix form.  However, this is not possible because the majority of my `c_i` constants have known variables that need to stay in their symbolic form.  So, I require a symbolic equation solver.

I have tried to code the system into sympy, which is a symbolic equation solver in python.  This is not fast enough for me.

I have tried to think of replacing my `c_i` values with prime numbers, and factoring out the prime numbers when I reach a solution.  However, this will not work either: Many of the constants within the `c_i` expression are in polynomial form.  The polynomials do not go higher than a power of 6.

Is there a solution for me?

1. Is there a symbolic equation solver that will solve my system quickly?
2. Is there another way to represent my system of equations so that I can solve it quickly?

My programming background is in python, C++, and R.  I am willing to learn new languages/systems in order to solve this problem.

Comment: It sounds like your computation is slow because the thing it's trying to compute is a symbolic expression of exponentially huge length.

Comment: Yes, and I do not know if there exists a symbolic equation solver that will give me an answer within a reasonable amount of time.  If I can even find one for the 30 equations and 30 unknowns case I will be very happy.

Comment: No software could ever possibly give you an exponentially huge amount of output in a reasonable time. Even if you had a magic answer machine that spits out answers immediately with zero time needed for computation, it would still take ages for the machine to spit out the entire answer.

Comment: Even if the answer is unwieldy and large, if the computer could spit out the answer within a month I would be happy.

Comment: I have currently a similar problem. For your case of 30 times 30 probably **sage** (sagemath to search) is enough (I tried it with 220 inequalities and 15 variables -> a few minutes calculating). It is even based on python (you can also do your calculations on cocalc.com). I am extremely unhappy with my case of 1000 inequalities and 45 variables, have you found a another way (I am happy with the existence or non-existence of a solution)?